# Apache Server Rewrite Rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have 3 rules for my websites that work without any problem on the pages of my site except the index. My index page is called ecorustic.php but i want it to display simply ecorustic without the extention.Now if i browser through the pages i get ecorustic/mountain/himalaya (it loses the extension) but when I return to home page, it displays ecorustic.php . PLS HELP

```
    # my .htacces file
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^ecorustic/.php$  index.php #i made it so the server views it as index
    RewriteRule ^ecorustic/(.*)/(.*)$  ecorustic.php?categorie=$1&nume=$2 
    RewriteRule ^ecorustic/(.*)$  ecorustic.php?categorie=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add * symbol after point.
    `RewriteRule ^ecorustic/.*php$  index.php`